# $(window).height() retorna valor igual à $(document).height()

Tags: javascript, jquery, height

eu estou com um probleminha bem chato.

Estou tentando pegar o "scrollBottom" da pagina, usando:

```
$(document).height() - ( $(this).scrollTop() + $(window).height() )
```

Fiz então uma "tabelinha" pra mostrar os dados na tela, e testei em outros sites (abrindo o site, e inserindo meu código no console do navegador):

[image: Exemplo da "tabela" em uma página do próprio SO]

Mas acontece que no meu site, o `$(window).height()` está retornando a altura da página HTML ao invés da janela do navegador:

[image: "tabela" na minha página]

O mais estranho é que isso ocorre mesmo que eu não tenha nada no script além de `$(document).ready()` ou `$(window).load()`. Mas não ocorre se tiver apenas o `$(window).height() )` (Dessa forma não tenho a tabela, mas o `$(window).height()` retorna o valor correto.

[image: Com $(document).ready()][image: Sem $(document).ready()]

E criar variáveis antes do `$(document).ready()` ou `$(window).load()` me gera o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Será que alguém ai tem alguma ideia do que pode ser isso?

Comment: Podes fazer um jsFiddle com o código que tens na página? Esse erro está meio estranho.

Comment: Acontece que é bem grande, uma página inteira
O script equivalente, apesar de que o erro não deve estar no script, já que mesmo sem comando algum, o erro ocorre

Comment: Bom, tentei copiar os códigos (HTMLS, CSS e JS) para o jsFiddle
Mas não está funcionando, creio que o javaScript não esteja rodando
Ele não da nenhum alerta, e carrusel que fiz também não executa
Não sei bem o que fazer ali, não conheço bem esse jsFiddle

De qualquer forma, eis os links:
Colaboration: https://jsfiddle.net/pk4kk8d8/#&togetherjs=H9F6VGqU7O
Share: https://jsfiddle.net/pk4kk8d8/

Comment: Como para o jsFiddle não estava funcionando bem, enviei para o jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/tonewiculi/1/

Desconfigurou um pouco, e perdeu umas coisas, como imagens, mas é o de menos
Para conferir inteiro, direto em um servidor acesse: http://jonatasamaral.comyr.com/sinharosa.com/

Comment: Eu testei pegar os tamanhos da página com o JavaScript puro, e funcionou bem. Criei uma barra sobrepondo a página, com cada forma de medida:
http://i.imgur.com/x4zDeDm.png
a parte branca é o tamanho da página.
Pelo que constatei:
window.innerWidth pega o tamanho da página contando com a barra de rolagem
window.outerWidth pega o tamanho de toda a janala do navegador
document.documentElement.clientWidth ou document.body.clientWidth pegam o tamanho interno da janela
window.width não funciona